# Why I am not able to attach onBlur to component created in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am learning react.js

I created an example where there is a textarea, 
If I enter comma seperated names in that textarea, I show a listing those
names below the textarea.

the working example is as follows, 
[click here](https://jsfiddle.net/rahulshivsharan/uxzx0xaL/1/)

The code is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>React Template</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">     
        <style type="text/css">
            .mywidth{
                width : 50%;
            } 
        </style>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Body Content -->
            <div id="mainContent"></div>
        <!-- Body Content -->

        <!-- The core React library -->
        <script src="/node_modules/react/dist/react.min.js"></script>
        <!-- The ReactDOM Library -->
        <script src="/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javaScript">
            (function(){
                'use strict'
                // custom javaScript content

                var DataFeedComponent = React.createClass({
                    propTypes : {
                        "defaultValue" : React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
                    },
                    getDefaultProps : function(){
                        return {
                            "content" : ""
                        }
                    },
                    getInitialState : function(){
                        return {
                            "content" : this.props.defaultValue
                        }
                    },
                    doRenderingUI : function(evt){                                              
                        this.setState({
                            content : evt.target.value
                        });
                    },
                    render : function(){
                        var TextAreaElement = React.createElement("textarea",{
                            "className" : "mywidth",
                            "value" : this.state.content,
                            "onChange" : this.doRenderingUI
                        });

                        var listElementArray = [];

                        var someContent = this.state.content.split(",");

                        for(var x = 0; x < someContent.length; x++){

                            if(someContent[x] !== undefined && someContent[x] !== null && someContent[x] !== ""){
                                listElementArray.push(React.createElement("li",null,someContent[x]));   
                            }                               

                        } // end of for

                        var orderedListingElement =  React.createElement("ol",null,listElementArray);

                        var DivElement = React.createElement("div",null,TextAreaElement,orderedListingElement);
                        return DivElement;
                    }
                });



                var elementObject = React.createElement(DataFeedComponent,{ "defaultValue" : "Victor,Nick" });

                ReactDOM.render(elementObject,document.getElementById("mainContent"));
            })();   
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So my problem is

on event 'onChange' my example works fine,

```
render : function(){
                        var TextAreaElement = React.createElement("textarea",{
                            "className" : "mywidth",
                            "value" : this.state.content,
                            "onChange" : this.doRenderingUI
                        });
```

i.e. on entering the text in textarea I am able to see the listing below the textarea.

BUT

if I change to onBlur, it doesn't work. why ?

Comment: You mean that you can't write any anything if you change onChange to onBlur?

Comment: It's good to avoid vague statements like "it doesn't work". Instead try to explain what happens. Like:   "I can't write anymore" or "I get an error in the console".

Answer (score 0):

You have your component's value set as a derivative of your `this.state.content`. This is what is called a *controlled component*, in order to change what appears in the field, you *must* change the React state every time something happens (i.e. when a button is pressed).

`onBlur` is not activated when the input changes, it's activated when you deselect the element. Hence your app never has a chance to actually change the input.

Answer (score 0):

Your component is a `controlled` component, since you have set `value` to your `Textarea`.

Everytime you type, `onChange` gets called, which in turn updates the state and that inturn updates the value in textarea. When you change to `onBlur`, your state is never set, and so when you type the value is not changing.

Simplest solution would be to change `value` to `defaultValue`, since i guess you want to pass initial value to your `Textarea` and that would look something like below

```
 var TextAreaElement = React.createElement("textarea",{
                        "className" : "mywidth",
                        "defaultValue" : this.state.content,
                        "onBlur" : this.doRenderingUI
                    });
```

But if you want the component to be still controlled, then you need to pass both `onChange` and `onBlur` and handle it appropriately.